# Websocket not being sent

Tags: javascript, php, json, websocket

I'm currently doing the following on PHP

```
$room_array = array();
$room_array[0] = 'room-list';
$room_array['info'] = array('room_name' => $room['room_name'], 'owner' => $username['username'], 'room_description' => $room['room_desc']);
socket_send($this->current_socket, $this->encode(json_encode($room_array)), strlen($this->encode(json_encode($room_array))), 0);
```

And this is my encode function

```
private function encode($text) 
    {
        $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
        $length = strlen($text);

        if($length <= 125)
            $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
        elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
            $header = pack('CCS', $b1, 126, $length);
        elseif($length >= 65536)
            $header = pack('CCN', $b1, 127, $length);

        return $header.$text;
    }
```

And on my client I'm processing it like this

```
message = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log(message)
        switch(message[0])
        {
            case 'error':
                alert(message[1]);
                break;
            case 'login-success':
                $('#user_information').html('<button class="user-name-button">Welcome <b>' + message.name + '</b></button><button class="user-coins-button"><b>' + message.coins + '</b> Coins</button>');
                socket.send(JSON.stringify({'room_list': message.name}));
                break;
            case 'room-list':
                alert(1)
                break;
        }
```

So with this code the alert(1) is being executed but the problem is if I try the following (adding more elements into the array) the socket wont work. The message will be sent but will never get to the client. Don't know why

```
$room_array = array();
    $room_array[0] = 'room-list';
    $room_array['test'] = 'hello';
    $room_array['info'] = array('room_name' => $room['room_name'], 'owner' => $username['username'], 'room_description' => $room['room_desc']);
    socket_send($this->current_socket, $this->encode(json_encode($room_array)), strlen($this->encode(json_encode($room_array))), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

use a singleton object.

```
$http->execute($room_array);
$room_array->parse_request(this->returnFive());
$http->send_request();

public returnFive(){
    return 5;
}
```

Comment: Your answer appeared in the Low Quality Review Queue. Please expand on your answer. You can edit it.